# How do I proceed after having sat an exam where the instructions and problems were, seemingly, logically incoherent?

Tags: exams, machine-learning

**TL;DR**

I sat a timed (2 hour) online (home) exam for an online (due to COVID) statistical/machine learning class. It seems clear to me that the exam instructions and problems are logically incoherent, and there was no possibility for me to request clarification during the exam. I emailed the professor immediately after the exam, but was only able to get a response days later after I spoke to a university student services office and they followed up with the professor. I was told by the office that the professor said that there is nothing wrong with the exam instructions or content. Despite this, it seems clear to me that the instructions do not make sense, and do not meet some minimum standard of clarity for such a timed online exam. **How do I proceed from here?**

**The details:**

I recently sat an online (due to COVID) undergraduate statistical/machine learning exam with the following instructions and problems:

[image]
[image]

Problem 1 clearly says "denote by DXT.V1 the raw DXT data without the variable Dx". I did that in the R programming language as follows:

```
DXT <- read.csv("examdata.csv") 
str(DXT)
```

[image]
(Original data)

```
DXT.V1 <- DXT[,-1] 
str(DXT.V1)
```

[image]
(Altered data, DXT.V1, Dx variable removed)

But, despite the fact that problems i., ii., and iii. clearly state that we are to use the dataset DXT.V1, problems ii. and iii. clearly state that we are to use the *classes*:
[image]

But we were just told to "denote by DXT.V1 the raw DXT data without the variable Dx", which means we have taken *out* the classes. It seems clear to me that this does not make sense at all and is logically incoherent. I thought it safest to follow the instructions that were stated clearly and explicitly, and so I did not do anything with the classes.

I have spent many hours going over this, but I just don't see how these instructions make sense. The more of the exam instructions you read, the more it seems clear that the instructions are logically incoherent and do not make sense. For example, for problem 1. (b) i., we can see that it says the same for the variable T6, in accordance with the "notation used for datasets in the questions" table (shown above):
[image]
For the sake of brevity, I have decided to not include the rest.

So, given what is stated explicitly, both in the problems and in the "notation used for datasets in the questions" table in the first image, it seems clear to me that all instructions provided in this paper support my actions, and there is no reasonable indication that I was supposed to do something else.

Under exam conditions (no one to ask for help/advice/clarification and timed), I had no way of asking anyone whether this was an error in the instructions, or whether I had misunderstood something. And so, given that it is a timed exam, I had no choice but to continue under the 'academically safest' assumption, which, in my opinion, was to follow the instructions as stated explicitly, rather than trying to 'read between the lines' or 'infer' what the instructions *might* mean (since the former is much more defensible than the latter). I sent an email to the course professor immediately after the exam, including a document highlighting the inconsistencies, seeking clarification as to whether there was an error.

After a total of two emails, and almost a week (almost 5 working days) with no response, I managed to get a response from the professor in question by indirect means through a university student administrative department. The individual from the student administrative department followed it up and informed me that they had spoken to the professor in question and that the professor had told them that they had seen my email and that there is nothing wrong with the instructions or any content in the exam.

Given that the inconsistencies that I outlined above mean that much of the exam problems are completely undoable, and the rest were done incorrectly (since I proceeded as the instructions stated, with the classes under the Dx variable not included), it is mathematically guaranteed that I failed the exam (and therefore the entire course, since the exam is 60% of the course grade). However, the exam results have not been released yet.

Also, due to the COVID situation, I was unable to sit the primary online exam with the rest of the course cohort, and so this exam that I sat was a special online exam at a different, unique time. This means that (1) the exam paper is different to the one done by the main cohort of students, and (2) I am not aware of anyone else who may have sat the exam.

As I said, I have spent many hours reading over and thinking about the exam instructions and problems, trying to figure out how they could make sense (could I have misunderstood them somehow? Is there a way to reasonably interpret them so that they make sense?). I have gone through all of the course material, including **practice exams** and assignments, trying to see if any previous material had instructions and problems worded similar to this, but, as I expected, there is nothing – everything prior to this was in mostly clear, canonical language that one would expect. For a timed exam (2 hours) with no possibility for clarification of instructions, I do not see how these instructions and problems satisfy some minimum acceptable standard of clarity. **How do I proceed from here?**

---

Comment: @scaaahu As I said in my post, this was not a possibility. I immediately sent an email to my professor after the exam (again, please read the entire post). My apologies if I was unclear.

Comment: I mean did you have a proctor available?

Comment: @scaaahu I had to look up the meaning of "proctor". No, there was no such person available. The online exam was to be done from home, and there was no one available to contact regarding such questions specific to the exam paper/content. We *were* told to contact a certain department in case of a problem unrelated to the exam/unit content (such as technical or scheduling problems), but that is a different matter.

Comment: @scaaahu As I said in the post, I do not know of anyone who sat the same exam as me. The exam I sat was not with the main cohort (see the second half of my post).

Comment: I understand that. My question is that did they have the same issue in the primary exam?

Comment: @scaaahu I do not personally know anyone in the course, so I couldn't ask. The entire class was online (due to COVID). For what it's worth, I did have access to practice exams (which I completed), but none of them had instructions similar to the exam I sat.

Comment: @scaaahu Ok, I will do that in a moment. Thanks.

Comment: @scaaahu Ok, done. How's that?

Comment: I would check first in another SE if your concern is motivated. If so, prepare your self and arrange a call or a meeting. But also wait for the exam to be evaluated...

Comment: I moved TLDR to the front. I guess you see that. I also deleted some comments I think is not necessary anymore. I hope someone else can give you some hints as how to proceed. I do think there should have been someone available to oversee the exam. But, Covid-19 changes everything they may not have anyone available just for you, who is the only one taking the exam. Very strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr: you did misunderstand the question, and there is a way to reasonably interpret it so that it makes sense. While the question could have been formulated in a slightly more precise manner, there is a straightforward interpretation, and there is a good reason why the instructor decided to separate the DXT.V1 and the Dx information. I doubt whether any further action you could take would lead to positive outcomes, so I would let it be if I were you.

---

For illustration, it may be instructive to look at parallel coordinate plots. [This is an example for the Iris dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates#/media/File:ParCorFisherIris.png)

There is a vertical axis for each input attribute. Each datapoint in the dataset is represented by a set of straight lines connecting the attribute values for that datapoint. The lines are colored according to the three classes available in the dataset.

If the instructor would have written as exam question "Make a parallel coordinate plot of the raw DXT data", there will be students who use the class as an attribute that is similar to all other attributes. Those students will make an extra vertical axis for the class attribute, and connect values just like for all other attributes. The instructor has tried to get you to not use the class as yet another vertical axis in this plot.

Hence, the questions are:

- compute some summary statistics over DXT.V1
- make a parallel coordinate plot of the contents of DXT.V1, where you represent the contents of Dx by distinct colors
- make a parallel coordinate plot of the contents of DXT.V1.sc, where you represent the contents of Dx by distinct colors
- comment on the differences between the plots of the scaled and unscaled versions

You write: "But, despite the fact that problems i., ii., and iii. clearly state that we are to use the dataset DXT.V1, problems ii. and iii. clearly state that we are to use the classes:". There is not necessarily a contradiction between the two: it can be necessary to use multiple bits of information to solve multiple parts of a problem. In this case, the problem clearly stated that you are to use the dataset DXT.V1, from which you should have derived that this information should determine the vertical axes and the positioning of the diagonal lines in the parallel coordinates plot. Problems ii. and iii. clearly state that you are to use the classes, from which you should have derived that this information should determine the color of the diagonal lines in the parallel coordinates plot.

It would have been helpful if the instructor would have made *explicit* that the class color coding can use information from Dx. But the instructor will likely voice the opinion that it should be obvious from context that class information from Dx can and should be used here, since it obviously cannot be obtained in another manner.

Comment: I am aware that I am focusing on the part of the questions that says "(could I have misunderstood them somehow? Is there a way to reasonably interpret them so that they make sense?)"; I feel that this is key, since it informs actions to be undertaken for the rest of the question. This does, however, make the question-answer combination stray deep into research content territory, which is not really what Academia.SE is for. If anyone feels that the Q/A should be moved, migrated, deleted, etcetera, I'd be perfectly fine with that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I see what you're saying, but, if the instructor wanted us to use Dx, I just don't understand why they would so explicitly and clearly state that we are to *remove* Dx and use the dataset DXT.V1. The presence of the table "datasets in the questions" even reinforces this. So, what you're saying is that, despite the fact that multiple points of instructions all explicitly state to not use Dx, we actually *are* supposed to use Dx, along with DXT.V1? Or am I misunderstanding you? Again, I appreciate you taking the time to post this answer.

Comment: They so explicity and clearly state this, to avoid the scenario outlined in the third paragraph of my full answer: otherwise there will be students who use the class as an attribute that is similar to all other attributes in the plots. I also disagree with your characterization: questions 1a(ii) and 1a(ii) do not forbid you from using Dx. These questions do not "explicitly state to not use Dx", they explicitly state to use DXT.V1 and class information. You convinced yourself that no other information than DXT.V1 could be used in these exercises, but the instructor neither wrote not meant that.

Comment: A layman's question. Could the instructor mean that Dx is not part of data, just some kind of labels?

Comment: @scaaahu interesting; perhaps. It might work that way in the instructor's head, though notice that the second paragraph of the first bit quoted from the exam ("The DXT data contain") implies that the class labels are found in the first column of the DXT data.